# Question regarding terminology used in a lemma

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, soft-question, terminology

I was reading my calculus notes and found the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $I$ and differentiable on its interior $I^•$. Then $f$ is increasing (strictly increasing) on $I$ if $f'(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in I^•$ (if $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in I^•$).

My question is: What does exactly "interior" mean in this particular context?

Comment: It is a topology term that means "the biggest open set contained in $I$." In that context, the interior of the interval $[a,b]$ is $(a,b)$, the interior of the interval $[a,b)$ is $(a,b)$, etc. I think that you've already guessed it: the interior of any interval with bounds $a$ and $b$ is $(a,b)$

Comment: Thank you! I had a notion of the term, but I didn't know the proper meaning of it.